# Is this a good way of reading from a text file?

Tags: java, file, io, filereader

I've been looking around on the Internet trying to figure out which could be the best way to read from text files which are not very long (the use case here involves small OpenGL shaders). I ended up with this:

```
private static String load(final String path)
{
    String text = null;

    try
    {
        final FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(path);
        fileReader.read(CharBuffer.wrap(text));

        // ...
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return text;
}
```

In which cases could this chunk of code result in inefficiencies? Is that `CharBuffer.wrap(text)` a good thing?

Comment: Have you tested this method? Did it return the text? `CharBuffer.wrap(text)` returns a read-only buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read the file line by line:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    String everything = sb.toString();
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```

If you want to read the complete file in one go:

String text=new String(Files.readAllBytes(...)) or Files.readAllLines(...)

Comment: How does the last method you mentioned behave in terms of efficiency when dealing with small files (say less than 50 lines, less than 50 chars per line)? I know this is a very broad question but still I'm interested in the answer.

Comment: http://ideone.com/JD5FS6
Time taken to read using bufferedReader 1
Time taken to read using readallBytes 11

 Actually BufferedReader is around 10 times more efficient than ReadAllBytes for a file that you have mentioned. Use BufferedReader for this.

Comment: That's [not an appropriate way to benchmark a Java program](http://stackoverflow.com/a/513259/4125191).

Answer (score 1):

I would usually just roll like this. The CharBuffer.wrap(text) thing seems to only get you a single character ... [File Reader docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html)

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String s; 
while((s = br.readLine()) != null) { 
   sb.append(s);
} 
fr.close(); 
return sb.toString();
```